# Is there a way to create a friendly url like site.com/state/127 and still point to a particular file like index.php

Tags: php, rest, .htaccess, endpoint

I am creating a rest api endpoint to input data into a database. I have been trying to rewrite the url into this format `http://example.com/src/public/endpoint/data`. The public in the url is a folder that had has an index.php file that all the urls will be routed to but it is not working. Below is my .htaccess code.

```
RewriteEngine 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/src/public/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I am getting the link address `http://example.com/src/public/?path=state/127&_=1579497796272` as the endpoint when i expect `example.com/src/public/state/127`. I know am not doing something correctly but i can not figure it out.

Comment: What isn't working? What address are you typing and what address appears to be fetched? The idea of URL rewriting in general is you're rewriting the "nice" URL (first part of `RewriteRule`) into the "real" one (second part), not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?path=(.*)&(.*)\sHTTP.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /src/public/%1? [L,R]
RewriteRule ^src/public/state/127 /src/public/?path=state/127&_=1579497796272 [L]
```

First you should add `on` after `RewriteEngine` which means enabling mod_rewrite .
The second line will captrue the request and get a part of query string.
Third line will externally redirect the request to be friendly.
The last line will redirect a new one, internally , to the correct path.

**Note:** if it is ok , change `R` to `R=301` to be permenant redirection.